# Extract data folder to sdcard in Android programming?

Tags: android, extract, android-sdcard

I have a folder, which has some data. I want when user open my app the first time, this folder will be extracted to sdcard of device.

What is solution? Can you help me please,

Comment: "I have a folder" -- where is this folder?

Comment: Is that a folder or a zip file?

Comment: It is a folder not zip file. Folder is placed in my application code